# Spark Exits with exception

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

This is the stackTrace that I am getting while running the application:

```
16/11/03 11:25:45 INFO CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint: Launching task 233 on executor id: 4 hostname: 10.178.149.243.
16/11/03 11:25:45 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.0 in stage 11.0 (TID 217, 10.178.149.243): java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:347)
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:345)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockInfoManager.releaseAllLocksForTask(BlockInfoManager.scala:343)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.releaseAllLocksForTask(BlockManager.scala:644)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:281)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

16/11/03 11:25:45 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 14.0 in stage 11.0 (TID 225) on executor 10.178.149.243: java.util.NoSuchElementException (None.get) [duplicate 1]
16/11/03 11:25:45 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 14.1 in stage 11.0 (TID 234, 10.178.149.243, partition 14, NODE_LOCAL, 8828 bytes)
16/11/03 11:25:45 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 22.0 in stage 11.0 (TID 232) on executor 10.178.149.243: java.util.NoSuchElementException (None.get) [duplicate 2]
16/11/03 11:25:45 INFO CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint: Launching task 234 on executor id: 4 hostname: 10.178.149.243.
16/11/03 11:25:45 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 22.1 in stage 11.0 (TID 235, 10.178.149.243, partition 22, NODE_LOCAL, 9066 bytes)
16/11/03 11:25:45 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 24.0 in stage 11.0 (TID 233) on executor 10.178.149.243: java.util.NoSuchElementException (None.get) [duplicate 3]
16/11/03 11:25:45 INFO CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint: Launching task 235 on executor id: 4 hostname: 10.178.149.243.
16/11/03 11:25:45 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 24.1 in stage 11.0 (TID 236, 10.178.149.243, partition 24, NODE_LOCAL, 9185 bytes)
16/11/03 11:25:45 INFO CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint: Launching task 236 on executor id: 4 hostname: 10.178.149.243.
16/11/03 11:25:45 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 22.1 in stage 11.0 (TID 235) on executor 10.178.149.243: java.util.NoSuchElementException (None.get) [duplicate 4]
16/11/03 11:25:45 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 22.2 in stage 11.0 (TID 237, 10.178.149.243, partition 22, NODE_LOCAL, 9066 bytes)
16/11/03 11:25:45 INFO CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint: Launching task 237 on executor id: 4 hostname: 10.178.149.243.
16/11/03 11:25:45 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 14.1 in stage 11.0 (TID 234) on executor 10.178.149.243: java.util.NoSuchElementException (None.get) [duplicate 5]
16/11/03 11:25:45 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 14.2 in stage 11.0 (TID 238, 10.178.149.243, partition 14, NODE_LOCAL, 8828 bytes)
16/11/03 11:25:45 INFO CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint: Launching task 238 on executor id: 4 hostname: 10.178.149.243.
16/11/03 11:25:45 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 24.1 in stage 11.0 (TID 236) on executor 10.178.149.243: java.util.NoSuchElementException (None.get) [duplicate 6]
16/11/03 11:25:45 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 24.2 in stage 11.0 (TID 239, 10.178.149.243, partition 24, NODE_LOCAL, 9185 bytes)
16/11/03 11:25:45 INFO CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint: Launching task 239 on executor id: 4 hostname: 10.178.149.243.
16/11/03 11:25:45 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 22.2 in stage 11.0 (TID 237) on executor 10.178.149.243: java.util.NoSuchElementException (None.get) [duplicate 7]
16/11/03 11:25:45 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 22.3 in stage 11.0 (TID 240, 10.178.149.243, partition 22, NODE_LOCAL, 9066 bytes)
16/11/03 11:25:45 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 14.2 in stage 11.0 (TID 238) on executor 10.178.149.243: java.util.NoSuchElementException (None.get) [duplicate 8]
16/11/03 11:25:45 INFO CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint: Launching task 240 on executor id: 4 hostname: 10.178.149.243.
16/11/03 11:25:45 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 14.3 in stage 11.0 (TID 241, 10.178.149.243, partition 14, NODE_LOCAL, 8828 bytes)
16/11/03 11:25:45 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 24.2 in stage 11.0 (TID 239) on executor 10.178.149.243: java.util.NoSuchElementException (None.get) [duplicate 9]
16/11/03 11:25:45 INFO CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint: Launching task 241 on executor id: 4 hostname: 10.178.149.243.
16/11/03 11:25:45 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 24.3 in stage 11.0 (TID 242, 10.178.149.243, partition 24, NODE_LOCAL, 9185 bytes)
16/11/03 11:25:45 INFO CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint: Launching task 242 on executor id: 4 hostname: 10.178.149.243.
16/11/03 11:25:45 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 22.3 in stage 11.0 (TID 240) on executor 10.178.149.243: java.util.NoSuchElementException (None.get) [duplicate 10]
16/11/03 11:25:45 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 22 in stage 11.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
16/11/03 11:25:45 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 12.0 (TID 243, 10.178.149.243, partition 0, NODE_LOCAL, 10016 bytes)
16/11/03 11:25:45 INFO CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint: Launching task 243 on executor id: 4 hostname: 10.178.149.243.
16/11/03 11:25:45 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 14.3 in stage 11.0 (TID 241) on executor 10.178.149.243: java.util.NoSuchElementException (None.get) [duplicate 11]
16/11/03 11:25:45 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Cancelling stage 12
16/11/03 11:25:45 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Stage 12 was cancelled
16/11/03 11:25:45 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 14.0 (TID 244, 10.178.149.243, partition 0, NODE_LOCAL, 7638 bytes)
16/11/03 11:25:45 INFO CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint: Launching task 244 on executor id: 4 hostname: 10.178.149.243.
16/11/03 11:25:45 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 24.3 in stage 11.0 (TID 242) on executor 10.178.149.243: java.util.NoSuchElementException (None.get) [duplicate 12]
16/11/03 11:25:45 INFO DAGScheduler: ShuffleMapStage 12 (show at RNFBackTagger.scala:97) failed in 0.112 s
16/11/03 11:25:45 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Cancelling stage 14
16/11/03 11:25:45 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Stage 14 was cancelled
16/11/03 11:25:45 INFO DAGScheduler: ShuffleMapStage 14 (show at RNFBackTagger.scala:97) failed in 0.104 s
16/11/03 11:25:45 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Cancelling stage 11
16/11/03 11:25:45 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Stage 11 was cancelled
16/11/03 11:25:45 INFO DAGScheduler: ShuffleMapStage 11 (show at RNFBackTagger.scala:97) failed in 0.126 s
16/11/03 11:25:45 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 12.0 (TID 243, 10.178.149.243): java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:347)
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:345)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockInfoManager.releaseAllLocksForTask(BlockInfoManager.scala:343)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.releaseAllLocksForTask(BlockManager.scala:644)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:281)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

16/11/03 11:25:45 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 7 failed: show at RNFBackTagger.scala:97, took 0.141681 s
16/11/03 11:25:45 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 12.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 22 in stage 11.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 22.3 in stage 11.0 (TID 240, 10.178.149.243): java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:347)
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:345)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockInfoManager.releaseAllLocksForTask(BlockInfoManager.scala:343)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.releaseAllLocksForTask(BlockManager.scala:644)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:281)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1450)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1438)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1437)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1437)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1659)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1618)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1607)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:632)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1871)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1884)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1897)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:347)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$execute$1$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2183)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withNewExecutionId(Dataset.scala:2532)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$execute$1(Dataset.scala:2182)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collect(Dataset.scala:2189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:1925)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:1924)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withTypedCallback(Dataset.scala:2562)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:1924)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2139)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:526)
    at com.knoldus.xml.RNFBackTagger$.main(RNFBackTagger.scala:97)
    at com.knoldus.xml.RNFBackTagger.main(RNFBackTagger.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:729)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:185)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:210)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:347)
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:345)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockInfoManager.releaseAllLocksForTask(BlockInfoManager.scala:343)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.releaseAllLocksForTask(BlockManager.scala:644)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:281)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
16/11/03 11:25:45 WARN JobProgressListener: Task start for unknown stage 12
16/11/03 11:25:45 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 14.0 (TID 244, 10.178.149.243): java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:347)
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:345)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockInfoManager.releaseAllLocksForTask(BlockInfoManager.scala:343)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.releaseAllLocksForTask(BlockManager.scala:644)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:281)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

16/11/03 11:25:45 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 14.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
16/11/03 11:25:45 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
16/11/03 11:25:45 WARN JobProgressListener: Task start for unknown stage 14
16/11/03 11:25:45 INFO SerialShutdownHooks: Successfully executed shutdown hook: Clearing session cache for C* connector
16/11/03 11:25:45 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 5.0 in stage 11.0 (TID 219) in 137 ms on 10.178.149.22 (1/35)
16/11/03 11:25:45 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://10.178.149.133:4040
16/11/03 11:25:45 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Shutting down all executors
16/11/03 11:25:45 INFO CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint: Asking each executor to shut down
16/11/03 11:25:45 ERROR TransportRequestHandler: Error while invoking RpcHandler#receive() for one-way message.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Could not find CoarseGrainedScheduler.
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Dispatcher.postMessage(Dispatcher.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Dispatcher.postOneWayMessage(Dispatcher.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcHandler.receive(NettyRpcEnv.scala:571)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.processOneWayMessage(TransportRequestHandler.java:179)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.handle(TransportRequestHandler.java:108)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead0(TransportChannelHandler.java:119)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead0(TransportChannelHandler.java:51)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:266)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at org.apache.spark.network.util.TransportFrameDecoder.channelRead(TransportFrameDecoder.java:85)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:846)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
16/11/03 11:25:45 ERROR TransportRequestHandler: Error while invoking RpcHandler#receive() for one-way message.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Could not find CoarseGrainedScheduler.
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Dispatcher.postMessage(Dispatcher.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Dispatcher.postOneWayMessage(Dispatcher.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcHandler.receive(NettyRpcEnv.scala:571)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.processOneWayMessage(TransportRequestHandler.java:179)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.handle(TransportRequestHandler.java:108)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead0(TransportChannelHandler.java:119)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead0(TransportChannelHandler.java:51)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:266)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at org.apache.spark.network.util.TransportFrameDecoder.channelRead(TransportFrameDecoder.java:85)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:846)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
16/11/03 11:25:45 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
16/11/03 11:25:45 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
16/11/03 11:25:45 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
16/11/03 11:25:45 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
16/11/03 11:25:45 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
16/11/03 11:25:45 ERROR TransportRequestHandler: Error while invoking RpcHandler#receive() for one-way message.
org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnvStoppedException: RpcEnv already stopped.
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Dispatcher.postMessage(Dispatcher.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Dispatcher.postOneWayMessage(Dispatcher.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcHandler.receive(NettyRpcEnv.scala:571)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.processOneWayMessage(TransportRequestHandler.java:179)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.handle(TransportRequestHandler.java:108)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead0(TransportChannelHandler.java:119)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead0(TransportChannelHandler.java:51)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:266)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at org.apache.spark.network.util.TransportFrameDecoder.channelRead(TransportFrameDecoder.java:85)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:846)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
16/11/03 11:25:45 ERROR TransportRequestHandler: Error while invoking RpcHandler#receive() for one-way message.
org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnvStoppedException: RpcEnv already stopped.
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Dispatcher.postMessage(Dispatcher.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Dispatcher.postOneWayMessage(Dispatcher.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcHandler.receive(NettyRpcEnv.scala:571)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.processOneWayMessage(TransportRequestHandler.java:179)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.handle(TransportRequestHandler.java:108)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead0(TransportChannelHandler.java:119)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead0(TransportChannelHandler.java:51)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:266)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at org.apache.spark.network.util.TransportFrameDecoder.channelRead(TransportFrameDecoder.java:85)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:846)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
16/11/03 11:25:45 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
16/11/03 11:25:45 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
16/11/03 11:25:45 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-c52a6da9-5702-4128-9950-805d5f9dd75e
```

Earlier I was not able to pin point the problem ! 
Then I tried the removing unncessary Code approach !

Then I found out  the problem lies in this :

```
 val groupedDF = selectedDF.groupBy("id").agg(collect_list("name"))
    groupedDF.show
```

Because if I try to show selectedDF it displays the correct result!

The spark version that I am using is 2.0.0 ! Please help me out and let me know what is the problem.

Link to Code is : 
https://gist.github.com/shiv4nsh/0c3f62e3afd95634a6061b405c774582

Show on line [19](https://gist.github.com/shiv4nsh/0c3f62e3afd95634a6061b405c774582#file-spark_exits_exception-L19) prints and the show on [28](https://gist.github.com/shiv4nsh/0c3f62e3afd95634a6061b405c774582#file-spark_exits_exception-L28) throws this exception.

Server Configuration: I have spark 2.0 running on 8 core worker with 10 gb memory and its running on centOS

Script for launching application:

```
./bin/spark-submit --class com.knoldus.Application /root/code/newCode/project1/target/deployable.jar
```

Any help is appreciated !

**Note:** The code works fine in local mode. This error is thrown when i try to run it on cluster.

Comment: All we can see from the stack trace is that some enumeration is not as expected (via java.util.NoSuchElementException) - can you include some of your code? You may need to debug a little to find the particular section causing this if your code is large.

Comment: upload the codes.

Comment: @chucknelson: there is a lot of code , and most of it i cannot share , I am not able to pin point the problem where is it ? From where did you get the enumeration part ?

Comment: @eliasah : Please look into this !

Comment: Please note that it works dine on local !

Comment: can you create a MVCE so we can reproduce the error ?

Comment: @eliasah: I have updated the code please check thanks !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had a similar issue and it turned out to be because of the fact that my application was creating a new SparkContext everytime it tried to reload load certain classes in the executors. It's very likely that the same problem in your case if the code that will need to be loaded by the executors to run certain steps is in the same 'logical context' as code that instantiates the SparkContext.
You need to make sure that your SparkContext is loaded only once at most simply by restructuring your code.

Comment: How do we make sure that SparkContext gets loaded at most once. Is it like suppose we initialize an instance variable in class against declaring it as a global variable in the code.

Comment: You can have global variables as long as they are not the sparkcontext or derived from running the spark context. I think all you need to look out for is that you place the context initializing code in a place where it won't run again after the first time.

Comment: I am using pyspark, all I had done was added a sparkcontext in a constructor of a class. Then after seeing this I added it as a global instance instead. I have no clue where I should put it next, where should it go so as to make it run only once. Would you be able to guide me if you have a reference or a link where I could read up more. I'll be grateful.

Comment: I don't have a straightforward reference to point you to. Can you post some code snippets, perhaps I or others can provide some help?
I don't know to much about python, but what you tried would probably be a problem in java as well since the constructor and the global instance would be evoked when the code is passed to the executor.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, too. It turned out I was inadvertently trying to call SparkContext inside a UDAF (which runs inside executors).

More details here: [How to collect a single row dataframe and use fields as constants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56757436/how-to-collect-a-single-row-dataframe-and-use-fields-as-constants)